# define golang type as a slice of other type in protobuf's .proto file

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I want to define a Go type in `.proto` file. The type is a slice of other type which is defined in `.proto` file.

I have types as below.

```
type SomeType struct {
    // few fields
}

type SomeTypes []SomeType
```

I have `SomeType` is defined in .proto file as below.

```
message SomeType {
    //
}
```

Now I want to define type `SomeTypes` in .proto file. But I have not found any way to do that. The simplest solution for me is to change type `SomeTypes` as below:

```
type SomeTypes struct {
    Content []SomeType
}
```

Then I can define that in .proto file as

```
message SomeTypes {
      repeated SomeType Content = 1 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
}
```

But I want to know if there is any solution which does not involve changing the struct `SomeTypes`

I am using `proto2`.

Comment: There's no straightforward way to create a proto that is simply a list/array/vector (call it what you will). It is very common to have `message MyMessage{...}` and `message MyMessageList { repeated MyMessage my_messages = 1; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that there is an issue created in protobuf project: https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/issues/433 so it is confirmed that there is no other way currently.